# How to remove any html tags with nothing but optional whitespace between them

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to clean up some VERY ugly html (think < span>< /span> < em>< /em> < em>  < /em> < strong>< /strong> ) over and over again...

I'm looking for a nice and easy preg_replace to eliminate any html tags that contain optional whitespace between them. Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Oh, and just found this beauty:

< p>< strong>< strong>< /strong>< /strong>< /p>

looks like this will need to live in a while loop as well.

Comment: This topic has been covered numerous times before.

Comment: And HTML is still not a regular language.

Comment: Perhaps the combination of the tags "regex" and "html" should automatically redirect to _that_answer_.

Answer (score 5):

It's funny how this topic keeps coming up.

[Don't go with regex](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).  Try [HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to really clean up some code, I'd suggest the [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) class in PHP.  There are [some examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.php) that might help get you started.  (Note this is a front-end to [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/))

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a regex, here's one:

```
s:<(\w+)>\s*<\/\1>::g
```

Run it multiple times to eliminate nested cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like tidy WAS the answer:

```
function cleanupcrap($html){
$tidy_config = array( 
     'clean' => true, 
     'output-xhtml' => true, 
     'show-body-only' => true, 
     'wrap' => 0,
     ); 

    $tidy = tidy_parse_string($html, $tidy_config, 'UTF8'); 
    $tidy->cleanRepair(); 
    return $tidy->value;
```

}